# Why do I have ROS Lunar on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ros, ubuntu-18.04

I am working with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Bionic Beaver.  I did `sudo apt install ros-desktop-full-dev`, and I was expecting to get ROS Melodic Morenia, but instead, I got Lunar.  Any idea why?  Any recommendations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not the recommanded way to install ROS on Ubuntu. Have a look at [the installation instructions for ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu). That way, you explicitly install the Melodic distribution. ROS Lunar is not officially supported on Ubuntu Bionic ([source](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar)).